# How to filter the handlebars {{#each}} results before displaying

Tags: python-2.7, ember.js, ember-data, handlebars.js

How to filter the handlebars {{#each}}  results before displaying

iam sending model data by using

```
rdata=$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/signin",
    data: JSON.stringify(cred),
    dataType: "json",
    async: false}).responseJSON;
  console.log(rdata);
  this.transitionToRoute('links',rdata);
```

and in my ember html am looping over this rdata to get the data..
but in the rdata there is a status field coming by which i want to filter the data and display in separate {{#each}} blocks can anyone help me out.

Iam a newbie